# App store says to remove unused In App Purchase While I cannot be able to delete it from itunes developer account

Tags: ios, app-store

I am unable to delete In App Purchase product whose state is *"Developer Removed From Sale"* from my developer account. The product details are, its auto-renew subscription of 3 months. Additionally, it is been removed from sale since 2017.

> Once I delete the in app purchase, the page auto refreshes and redirects to home page and when gets back to in app purchase products listing page it re appears there and the cycle continues every single time I try to delete.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Please contact Apple Developer support. We cannot really help with problems of App Store Connect: https://developer.apple.com/contact